# Android: Manifest merger failed CoreComponentFactory

Tags: android, android-manifest

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>
> is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>
> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-33:19 to override.

My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="midhilaj.in">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application

        android:name=".App"
        android:debuggable="false"
        tools:replace="android:icon "
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="dataa.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME"
            android:value="midhilaj.in" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Registation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Android grade

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
}
```

Note error removed after removing:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
```

Comment: I fixed this issue by adding below two line in to build.gradle file.                                            
googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"

firebaseVersion = "17.3.4"

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into the same problem and after a bit of search i found this issue here:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1429

Here the creator of library has suggested that either you migrate to `androidX` or downgrade the library version to the compatible one.For now i am using following:

```
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.0'
```